# Including Microsoft Office Spell Checker in own application

Tags: com, vb6, ms-office, spell-checking

I heard a while ago that the Microsoft Office Spell Checker could be included in own application by using the COM interface of it. Someone remembers the details? Which dll, or which ActiveX Object was it?

Answer (score 1):

I have been investigating this just a month ago. It seems that it was possible, but if I remember well since Office 2003 the embeddable COM component has been removed. You will have to look for older versions if you want to do so. Unfortunately I don't have any link, but it took me few minutes to find the appropiate explanations in Microsoft forums.

I have been evaluating some commercial editors with spellchecking support, so we'll buy one of these.

BTW, I need multiple languages so I looked for alternatives to Microsoft, but for english and another couple of languages, you can use directly Microsoft Rich text editor. I didn't play with it however.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the info! Please let me know if you find something with a cheap redistributable license (if one exists *g), so we need to buy it only once.

Comment: I need to support multiple languages, so we are going with DevExpress, with WinForms version embedded inWPF. We use this because supports better check as you type, and you can use any dictionary from Open Office, for example.