# How to use Microsoft office dictionary in a project based on Windows application?

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Including Microsoft Office Spell Checker in own application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535550/including-microsoft-office-spell-checker-in-own-application)

How can I use Microsoft office custom dictionary, through which we can get hint about any spelling and grammatical mistakes, in my project which is based on Windows application using visual studio 2008 with c# .net as language?